# Programmatically Launch OS X App after restart

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am currently needing an application to launch after the user restarts their computer. They will be running an application that will prompt a restart, after the restart, I need another application to launch. Or, if I could put code in the previous application that is causing the restart, to open a different application after restart. I have found some different code but it seems to be older versions. What is the most effective way to do this in a Cocoa OS X Application with Swift.

Comment: Maybe you should present those "older" and different code(s) you've found, and someone might pick up on that.

Comment: Do you mean having an application to launch (1) without having been put neither to _startup items_ nor to _login items_? (2) to behave like a _system daemon_, yet to appear as "Cocoa app" to the casual user, and (3) to be written in swift? That's quite a lot to ask for.

Comment: I may have found a different way to do it using the MDM, but I am wondering if there is a way to programmatically auto launch an application after the computer restarts without using the MDM.